# RethinkDB Time Query Issue

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm trying to run what seems like it should be a pretty basic query from the Data Explorer:

r.db("test").table("test_table").group(r.row('date').dayOfWeek())

where date is a **TIME** obj

I'm getting the following error:

e: Error in time logic: Year is out of valid range: 1400..10000 in:
r.db("test").table("test_table").group(r.row("date").dayOfWeek())

Any date/time function I try and use on the "date" field gives me the same error.

Here is an example of objects I have stored in the table:

{"iat":{"$reql_type$":"TIME","epoch_time":1467895446.724,"timezone":"-06:00"},"id":"0212197a-4891-4475-a30d-ebebc34ba0e4","minutes":152.78329467773438,"date":{"$reql_type$":"TIME","epoch_time":1467784800,"timezone":"-06:00"}}

Comment: Can you please give an example of the data you're querying so I can replicate? The query looks broadly ok.

Comment: I have added an object that is stored in the table for reference to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

One of your documents has a year that is not supported by `dayOfWeek`. The [RethinkDB documentation](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/dates-and-times/) has this to say:

> Most date operations are only defined on years in the range [1400, 10000] (but note that times in the year 10000 cannot be printed as ISO 8601 dates).

You can probably find the offending documents using a query like this:

```
var limit = r.ISO8601("1400-01-01T00:00Z")
r.table('test_table').filter(r.row('iat').lt(limit).or(r.row('date').lt(limit))
```